# Creating a new table that connects to the primary key of previous table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

Currently I have one table in a mySQL Database that I want to connect to another table I need to create. The second table is just going to have 2 columns, the member_id and product column. There is to be many entries in the product column for the same member_ID and the product column is to be a foreign key for another table.

Here is the SQL code I used to create the initial Login table:

```
'CREATE TABLE `members`(  
`member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`login` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',
`passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',
PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)) 
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

If someone could show me how to create the second table to connect to member_id that would be great.

Comment: You can read up on the MySQL foreign key syntax on its [documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). As mentioned by others, you need to use the InnoDB engine when creating your tables, in order to use FK's.

Comment: try using merge storage engine which combines your first and second tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyISAM storage engine does not support foreign keys. If You want to ensure data integrity by using foreign keys You need to use another storage engine eg. InnoDB

Using MyISAM You can't define a foreign key but You can still define the tables as following:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb9c/1/0

Please note that it is important to create the indexes to ensure decent performance for joins. If You want to use InnoDB and foreign keys then the explicit index creation is not needed as adding a foreign key creates an implicit index.

Comment: Question was probably updated after my answer. I've edited the answer. Should be more helpful now.